# SQLServer7 + VB6 EXE File does not run on Win7

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, sql-server-7

How can I use my old VB6 customized SQLServer database application in Windows 7?

I can not upgrade my old VB6 EXE file.

Comment: What error have you had installing/running it to make you think you have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

**VB6 Apps:**

You can run 32-bit VB6 apps in windows 7.

The full scope of support is detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

There is a thread here that covers some bits and bobs you may need to cover off: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/vb6-executable-will-not-run-in-win-7-64-bit/05c506d7-2ae9-4abd-91d6-9481b4b243e0

The main thing to realize is that you may have to manually install some of the pre-requisits you would have expected to be there by default on other windows versions.

**SQL Server 7:**

This may be more insteresting. You can certainly run a newer version of SQL Server and set the compatability level of your database as required - this may be sufficient.

I'd be surprise if you were able to install SQL Server 7 itself on Windows 7

Comment: SQL Server 2000 can't be installed on Windows 7, so surely you are correct about SQL Server 7 not being compatible. I was upset to find out that Enterprise Manager for 2000 couldn't be installed on my Win 7 PC so I could manage our old SQL 2000 server with the native tool.

Comment: You can download and install SQL Server Management Studio Express for SQL2005+.  This tool is a free download from Microsoft and will allow you to administer older SQL Servers.  It has Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer functionality in one app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQL Server 7, but VB6 will definitely run on Windows 7.

Comment: No you don't need to run a VM - VB6 (including the IDE) runs fine on Windows 7 64 bit - I am running it now!

Comment: Updated my answer... I'd heard that VB6 didn't run on Windows 7 64 bit, but I had no first hand knowledge.